# YUI multiple file upload issues in safari

Tags: php, flash, yui-uploader

I am using YUI uploader. It is working fine in chrome and firefox, In safari browser its working for single file upload. When i select multiple files it shows only 0 bytes. can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Safari bug ... still unfixed.

For workaround allowing using multiple where possible, but disable it for safari (thus preventing errors), see here:

[Any workarounds for the Safari HTML5 multiple file upload bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766644/any-workarounds-for-the-safari-html5-multiple-file-upload-bug/17515693#17515693)